# ServiceStack - how to write AllowHtml attribute?

Tags: servicestack

We have ServiceStack request:

```
MyRequest{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need deny all html in all requests by default, and allow html only if I have [AllowHtml] attribute. Like in MVC.

```
MyRequest{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Is it possible in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How we made that:
1. Add plugin for check HTML

```
public class SecurityValidationFeature : IPlugin
{
    private readonly ISecurityValidator[] _validators;

    public SecurityValidationFeature(ISecurityValidator[] validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }
```

2. Interface for DTO with method:

```
    public virtual Dictionary<string, string> StringFieldsAsEnum
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, FieldValue>()
                {
                    {"Name", new FieldValue(this.Name, AllowHtml)},
                    {"Fio", new FieldValue(this.Fio, AllowHtml)},
                    {"Email", new FieldValue(this.Email, AllowHtml)},
                    {"Post", new FieldValue(this.Post, AllowHtml)}
                };
        }
    }
```

3. And finally check in validator:

```
   public void Validate(Dictionary<string, FieldValue> fields)
    {
        if (fields == null || fields.Count == 0)
            return;

        Dictionary<string, string> failed = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Value.Value))
                continue;

            if (IsXssInjectible(field.Value))
            {
                failed.Add(field.Key, field.Value.Value);
            }
        }

        if (failed.Count > 0)
            throw new XssException(failed);
    }

    private bool IsXssInjectible(Field field)
    {
        return !field.AllowHtml && HasHtmlTags(field.Value);
    }

    private bool HasHtmlTags(string input)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(input, "<.*?>"); //проверяем любые закрытые теги
    }
```